# can't get firebase userID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie to firebase and Javascript and I have tried many methods get the user data store by the userid but all i'm getting is the data is being stored under "undefined".

here is my JS code

```
function handleRegister() {
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
     console.log(email);
     console.log(fname);

        if (email.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter an email address.');
        return;
      }
      if (password.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter a password.');
        return;
      }

      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function(user) {
        var uid = user.uid;
         var postData = {
            Firstname: fname,
            Lastname: lname,
            email: email,
      };
        // Get a key for a new Post.
      var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('Users').push().uid;

      var updates = {};
      updates['/Users/' + newPostKey] = postData;
      // updates['/user-posts/' + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
      return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
      })
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is that after a new user has been registered, I want to save the user info(i.e first and last name) into the database under their respective uid generated during authentication. 
but currently i can't get the uid and new user replaces previously entered user in DB instead of being entered as a new entry.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're complicating things a bit, by combining parts from the samples.

Saving the user that has just registered takes this:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .then(function(user) {
   var root = firebase.database().ref();
   var uid = user.uid;
   var postData = {
      Firstname: fname,
      Lastname: lname,
      email: email
   };
   root.child("Users").child(uid).set(postData);
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I wish i can up vote but i don't have enough points

Comment: Good to hear that it helped. You should be able to accept my answer (if not now yet, then later) by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Comment: Thank you again for that